# Visual studio .CreateInputLayout stuff

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, direct3d

```
InputLayout::InputLayout(Graphics& gfx,
    const std::vector<D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC>&layout,
    ID3DBlob* pVertexByteCode) : pInputLayout(&layout)
{
    INFOMAN(gfx);

    GFX_THROW_INFO(GetDevice(gfx)->CreateInputLayout(
        layout.data(), (UINT)layout.size(),
        pVertexByteCode->GetBufferPointer(),
        pVertexByteCode->GetBufferSize(),
        pInputLayout.GetAddressOf()));
}
```

The problem is that after compiling this code I get:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\winrt\wrl\client.h(252,45): error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'U *' to 'ID3D11InputLayout *'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            U=const std::vector<D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC,std::allocator<D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC>>
1>        ] (compiling source file InputLayout.cpp)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\winrt\wrl\client.h(252,45): message : Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast (compiling source file InputLayout.cpp)
1>D:\visual studio\prog\GameprojDirect3d\GameprojectDirect3D\GameprojectDirect3D\InputLayout.cpp(10): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11InputLayout>::ComPtr<const std::vector<D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC,std::allocator<D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC>>>(U *) noexcept' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            U=const std::vector<D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC,std::allocator<D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC>>
1>        ]
1>D:\visual studio\prog\GameprojDirect3d\GameprojectDirect3D\GameprojectDirect3D\InputLayout.cpp(9): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11InputLayout>::ComPtr<const std::vector<D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC,std::allocator<D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC>>>(U *) noexcept' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            U=const std::vector<D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC,std::allocator<D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC>>
1>        ]
```

The error is at the first argument of CreateInputLayout, it seemed to me that vector type causes it (somehow) so I created an array instead but it didn't work

```
InputLayout::InputLayout(Graphics& gfx,
    const std::vector<D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC>&layout,
    ID3DBlob* pVertexByteCode) : pInputLayout(&layout)
{
    INFOMAN(gfx);
    const D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC ied[] =
    {
        {"Position", 0u, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0}
    };
    GFX_THROW_INFO(GetDevice(gfx)->CreateInputLayout(
        ied, (UINT)layout.size(),
        pVertexByteCode->GetBufferPointer(),
        pVertexByteCode->GetBufferSize(),
        pInputLayout.GetAddressOf()));
}
```

This causes the same error.
I was confused because it worked in other file with similar syntax

```
wrl::ComPtr<ID3D11InputLayout> pInputLayout;
const D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC ied[] = 
{ 
    {"Position", 0u, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0}, 
    {"Color", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM, 0, 12u, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0}
};
GFX_THROW_INFO(pDevice->CreateInputLayout(ied, (UINT)std::size(ied), pBlob->GetBufferPointer(), pBlob->GetBufferSize(), &pInputLayout));
```

Note: GetDevice(gfx) returns ID3D11Device* which is main graphics device and pInputLayout (in previous code) is from diffrent class

Comment: Wrong line, it is complaining about the `pInputLayout(&layout)` initialization.  Just remove it or initialize to nullptr.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks a lot, this solves the error